# Kafka Streams: one of two TimestampExtractors doesn't get called

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Having a strange problem in my sample Kafka Streams application.
I have the following 2 KStreams:

```
KStream stream1 = builder.stream("topic1", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())
    .withTimestampExtractor(new Extractor1()))
    ...

KStream stream2 = builder.stream("topic2", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())
    .withTimestampExtractor(new Extractor2()))
    ...
```

They are built from the same StreamsBuilder `builder` that is configured with `KafkaStreams` properties *without* `StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG` property set at all (I've also trying setting it).

The problem I am observing is that the `extract()` method of my first `TimestampExtractor` `Extactor1` gets called, but the `extract()` method of my second `Extactor2` doesn't get called at all (event though the messages flow through both streams).

What could be the reason?

Comment: Not sure. Should work as expected. What version are you using? Can you reproduce the issue using TopologyTestDriver?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this @Matthias J. Sax! At the moment it looks like my mistake, no messages are flowing through it at all.

Comment: Records with negative timestamp would be dropped. Maybe double check for this case?

Comment: Thank you @MatthiasJ.Sax for the support. It has confirmed to be my mistake. I fixed my internal KStreams creation (by switching to Spring Cloud Stream and its Kafka Streams Binder) and both timestamp extractors started to kick in as expected:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039706/timestampextractorbeanname-setting-in-the-spring-cloud-stream-application-doesn/62044705
Will probably leave this question here hanging.